# Maya Python: mel.eval(invertSelection;) not working

Tags: python, maya, mel

Pretty much exactly as the title states, I've got a simple python script in Maya that isn't functioning.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

def createCylinder():
    # Check if cylinder "trunkCylinder" exists. Delete it
    if cmds.objExists("trunkCylinder"):
        cmds.delete("trunkCylinder")
    # Create a new cylinder called "trunkCylinder"
    cmds.polyCylinder(axis=(0,1,0), height=1, name="trunkCylinder" )
    # Clear the selection, then select the cap and invert the selection.
    cmds.select(clear=True)
    cmds.select("trunkCylinder.f[21]", replace=True)
    invertedSel = mel.eval("invertSelection;")
    print str(invertedSel)
    # ^^ Prints: None ^^
    # End result is nothing is selected

createCylinder()
```

I expected Maya to print a list of all faces on trunkCylinder except f[21] and to inverse the selection in the viewport. Instead, it returns None and deselects f[21]. Does anyone see a mistake in my code, or am I using invertSelection incorrectly?

Fortunately I can just select f[0:20] as a workaround, or even get a list of the faces and compare it to my list of faces, removing anything that is on both lists. However I can already envision situations where getting invertSelection to work would save me a lot of time. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Ran into this same problem on a script that worked in Maya 2016, but doesn't in Maya 2018.  Accepted answer worked for me.  Interestingly, the "invertSelection" script works if you perform those operations from the GUI, but not when you do them from script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Python script is definitely works. You should try it)). Asterisk is used for selection of all the other faces in array, along with `toggle` flag, that inverted a selection for you.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def createCylinder():
    if cmds.objExists("trunkCylinder"):
        cmds.delete("trunkCylinder")
    cmds.polyCylinder(axis=(0,1,0), height=1, name="trunkCylinder")
    cmds.select(clear=True)
    cmds.select("trunkCylinder.f[21]")
    cmds.select("trunkCylinder.f[*]", tgl=True)

createCylinder()
```